# My android can't log in to Wifi networks with Captive Portals

Tags: wi-fi

It used to work about a month ago.

Whenever I went to the mall, or this one coffee shop, and also at 7-11 outlets, I would get the notification "Sign in to wifi network", then I get redirected to their login page when trying to visit any webpage in my browser, I sign in, and I can connect after.

But I have been playing around with my android in the past month

- installed AFWall+ to allow only Opera Mini to connect on 3G
- installed ProxyDroid to view the traffic on one of my games (and to get infinite gold lol)
- added Charles Proxy certificate
- installed and uninstalled XPosed framework
- other stuff

And I just recently realized, I never get the "Sign in to wifi network" notification anymore, and I just get a cannot connect error on the browser.

It seems my phone's ability to sign in to captive portals has been completely broken somewhere along the way. It used to work 100%, now NONE of the places work.

Is there any way I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In afwall there should be a program listed as CaptivePortalLogin. Give that program permission to access internet.

Comment: Can you provide more details, please.

Answer (score -1):

For my xperia phone, stamina mode was the culprit. Disable stamina mode and everything works fine.